# Sorting large fixed-length record file

Tags: linux, sorting

It is easy to sort a large (=does not fit in memory, fits on local filesystem) text file using GNU sort. When necessary, GNU sort will start doing external merges.

How do I sort large files where instead of lines I have fixed-length records: no record delimiter, each record has for example 32 bytes of data that can include bytes of any value (including `\0` and `\n`)?

Comment: Inefficient but works: convert to hex+NL with `xxd -p -c 32` then sort then convert back with `xxd -r -p`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: nice idea. Could you post it as an answer?